# EXECEL what is the wrong with this formula always get this error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

i tried to change the cells format but no think is happened still there is problem

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure all your data is actually **numeric**? Most likely `B2:B4` is text.

Comment: Select one of the value cells. If you see the $ sign **in the formula bar**, then it's text.

Comment: @JvdV i tried to change the cells format if that you mean but no think, but i will google what you mentioned now .

Comment: @Rory i think you are right Mr , i will google to how to change it much thanks .

Comment: Select the cells, press Ctrl+H, enter a $ sign in the find box, leave the replace box empty, and press Replace All.

Comment: @Roryi appreciate your help thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to say that best way would be as @Rory suggested in the comments. He said:

> *Select the cells, press Ctrl+H, enter a $ sign in the find box, leave the replace box empty, and press Replace All.*

**It's easier to work if you input your data the right way.**

Anyways, this may work for you:

[image]

The formula I've used is:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VALUE(SUBSTITUTE(B2:B4;"$";"")))/B5
```